# How to share the author's archive?

Tags: archives, author, links

```
<hr>
    <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Forums', 'bbpress' ); ?></h3>

    <?php if ( bbp_get_user_last_posted() ) : ?>

        <p class="bbp-user-last-activity"><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Last Activity: %s',  'bbpress' ), bbp_get_time_since( bbp_get_user_last_posted(), false, true ) ); ?></p>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <p class="bbp-user-topic-count"><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Topics Started: %s',  'bbpress' ), bbp_get_user_topic_count() ); ?></p>
    <p class="bbp-user-reply-count"><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Replies Created: %s', 'bbpress' ), bbp_get_user_reply_count() ); ?></p>
    <p class="bbp-user-forum-role"><?php  printf( esc_html__( 'Forum Role: %s',      'bbpress' ), bbp_get_user_display_role() ); ?></p>
</div>
```

Hi! I would like to get a link to the author's archive here. how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

That's [get_the_author_posts_link()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_posts_link/):

```php
<?php echo get_the_author_posts_link(); ?>
```

If you want the author link for someone who isn't the author of this page in WordPress terms - I don't know what the bbpress state here is - then you can construct this from IDs instead (based on [a snippet from twentytwentyone](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.8/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/template-parts/post/author-bio.php) as you can see):

```php
$author_id = bbp_get_user_id();
$author_data = get_userdata( $author_id );
if ( $author_data ) {
    printf(
        '<a class="author-link" href="%1$s" rel="author">%2$s</a>',
        esc_url( get_author_posts_url( $author_id ) ),
        sprintf(
            /* translators: %s: Author name. */
            esc_html__( 'View all of %s\'s posts.', 'twentytwentyone' ),
            $author_data->display_name
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: This is a forum profile, but a user can also post on my site and I would like a link to these posts on their profile.